# Ignore non-connected nodes in NetworkX Graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a network diagram where a node is connected to another node which in-turn is connected to another node, worked through a logic to ignore when there is only one neighbour but that is still leaving few bits back. The attached diagram does a better job explaining it

[image]

I need to only keep where a **red-node** is connected to a **blue-node** or another **red-node** through a green node. Data used

[image]

```
for u, v in CA_new.edges:
    
    if len(list(CA_new.neighbors(v))) == 1 and len(list(CA_new.neighbors(u))) == 1:
        removeNodeslist.append(v)
        removeNodeslist.append(u)
    else:
        keepNodeslist.append(v)
        keepNodeslist.append(u)
CA_new.remove_nodes_from(removeNodeslist)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Perhaps answering the following could clear things up: for the example in the diagram, **which nodes exactly** should be kept (or which should be removed)?  The statement "I need to only keep where a red-node is connected to a blue-node or another red-node through a green node" is too vague.

Comment: Based on your explanation, I suspect that in your example, nodes D, L, M2, M4, M5, N3, N5 should be removed. However, it is not clear to me whether or not there are other nodes that should be removed. For example, what about X1?

Comment: yes, that is correct, nodes D, L, M2, M4, M5, N3, N5 should be removed from the map while nodes (/cluster) A,B,E,X1,X2,Y1,M3,M7 and C,H,M1,M8,M9 should exists. Parent A and B together have child Y1 while parent D is a single parent with 2 childs M2 and M3. We only need to show children only when a parent is linked to another parent. No single parent and children should be shown

Comment: What's the difference between red nodes and blue nodes? I thought that the red nodes are the ones with at least one colored edge, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, it sounds like you’re looking for the **connected components** that contain at least two parent nodes, and at least one of those parents has a colored edge. With that in mind, you can do something like the following:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Parent': list("EEABEHDILGKCDBLLFBCCJ"),
    'Child':  ["X1","X2","Y1","Y1","Y1","M1","N3","N4","N5","N7","N8","M1","M2",
               "M3","M4","M5","M6","M7","M8","M9","P7"],
    'Colour': list("NNNNYYNYNNNYNNNNYNNNN")
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source = 'Parent', target = 'Child')
parent_set = set(df['Parent'])
colored_parent_set = set(df.loc[df['Colour']=='Y','Parent'])

node_set = set()
for comp in nx.connected_components(G):
    if (len(comp & parent_set) >= 2 and
        comp & colored_parent_set):
        node_set |= comp

H = G.subgraph(node_set)

colors = ['limegreen']*len(H)
for i,n in enumerate(H.nodes):
    if n in colored_parent_set:
        colors[i] = "red"
    elif n in parent_set:
        colors[i] = "deepskyblue"

nx.draw(H, node_color = colors, with_labels = True)
```

Here's the result that I get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, I used your logic around sub-graphs and got the maps working. Thank you